# Python strptime for lists and milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

Hopefully 2 quick questions...

I have a datastring that is stored in a dictionary of dictionaries. I.e

```
data['<ITEM NUM>']['<time>']
```

My first question is this: Can I use this data structure directory in strptime? With my first few attempts I was getting error message saying:`Must be string, not list`

Secondly, my time tag is stored in this format `HH:MM:SS.f` but the milliseconds has 5 digits. Is there a quick way to resolve this since strptime's %f format only accepts 3 digits?

Update:
Well either way, I still have 5 digits for milliseconds and strpdate does not seem to like that when I pass in my string. Besides adding a 0 the end of it  is there a way to get it to convert it without having to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think strptime knows anything about the structure of your list? Additionally, `strptime`'s `%f` accepts 6 digits, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

`strptime()` takes a string and a format as the input. It doesn't traverse a list of items. You can easily accomplish this with a simple loop over your dict.

```
for key in data.keys():
    timeobj = time.strptime(data[key], '%H:%M:%S.%f')
    (do something with the time object ...)
```